# add dynamic input fields as array and store into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, input

I have this input field in a form that goes into database

```
<div id="cities">
    <input type="text" name="city[]" id="1" > 
        <input type="button" id="add_city()" onClick="addCity()" value="+" />
</div>
```

This is a javascript that adds or deletes extra fields

```
var i = 1;
function addCity(){
if (i <= 20){
    i++;    
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.style.color = "white";
    div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="city[]" id="'i'" ><input type="button" id="add_city()" onClick="addCity()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeCity(this)">';
    document.getElementById('cities').appendChild(div);
   }
}

function removeCity(div) {  
   document.getElementById('cities').removeChild( div.parentNode );
   i--;
}
```

up to here it all seems ok but when I run this code

```
if(is_array($city)){
  while(list($key,$cities) = each($city)){
        $sql4 = "INSERT INTO states (custId,State,country,city) 
                VALUES ('$custId','$value','$country','$cities')";
        $q4 = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql4) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
  }
}
```

I only get one result, the database stores only one row custId works State works Country works exept $cities it only gets store one time even if I input more cities  can anyone help me

I copied it from

```
if(is_array($state)){
   while(list($keys,$value) = each($state)){
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO states (custId,State,country,city) 
                 VALUES ('$custId','$value','$country','$city')";
        $q3 = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    }
}
```

the above code comes from texboxes in the same form and it works

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sendInfo.php" method="POST">
 Id:           <input name="custId" id="custId">         
 Name:         <input name="name" id="name">
 Address:      <input name="address" id="address">
 City:         <div id="cities">
               <input type="text" name="city[]" id="1" > 
               <input type="button" id="add_city()" onClick="addCity()" value="+" />
               </div>
 State:        <?php include ("../maps/states3.php");?>
 Zip Code:     <input type="text" name="zipCode">
 Country:      <select name="country" id="country"  style="width: 150px;">
               <option value="United States">United States</option>
               </select>
 Link:         http:// <input name="url" id="url">
 Category:     <input name="category" id="category">
 Phone:        <input name="phone" id="phone">
 Fax:          <input name="fax" id="fax" >
 e-mail:       <input name="email" id="email">
 Order Number: <input name="orderNumber" id="orderNumber" >
 Image name:   <input name="image" id="image">
 Chose sites to be displayed:
               <input type="radio" value="yes" name="site1"> Site1 <br />
               <input type="radio" value="yes" name="site2"> Site2 <br />
               <input type="radio" value="yes" name="site3"> Site3 <br />
 Start time:   <input type="date" name="start">   
 Stop time:    <input type="date" name="stop">   
 Table:        <?php include ("tables2.php");?>                
 Comments:     <textarea name="comments" id="comments" title="comments" >
               </textarea> 
               <input name"submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: And how exactly are you getting the cities back to PHP ?

Comment: @adeneo the database stores only one row

Comment: @adeneo or instead of a value it stores the word array

Comment: There must be something you are not showing us. Etc as @adeneo points out, how are you submitting the city to the php?

Comment: this is a part of a big form is divided into sections this is the only section that does not work it all comes from $_POST['']

Comment: print_r($cities); shows 1 result

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to write value property for text box

```
  <input type="text" name="city[]" id="1" > instead of this use 

   <input type="text" name="city[]" id="1" value="1" >
```

and before query you can see all values posted by using print_r($array) and better use foreach like this

```
 foreach($city as $key=>$value){
     echo $key."-----".$value;
 }


 if(count($state)){
    foreach($state as $key=>$val){//$val will contain state value while $key will contain key or index of array.
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO states (custId,State,country,city) 
             VALUES ('$custId','$val','$country','$city')";
    $q3 = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
}
```

}